# Could I use maven and dependency-check-maven plugin to validate contens of ear file?

Tags: maven, owasp

Is it possible to use maven and dependency-check-maven plugin to validate contens of already built ear file ? I'm trying something like below but I have no idea where I could point file which I want to verify

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
      <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.6</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found resolution. I point directory under plugin level. It forces plugin to check all files placed there

```
<configuration>
  <scanSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>\f1\f2\f3</directory>
    </fileSet>
  </scanSet>
</configuration>
```